# Twitter sign in ios app with using ionic capacitor-twitter plugin- Not working (ionic with angular)

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

[image]

when call  twitter.login() function that time error has occur,
it's working fine for android OS but not working on IOS
we use this code for sign in

```
twitter.login()
      .then(async result => {
       console.log(result.userID);
       
      }) 
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

can please any one help me
thanks

Comment: Do you have Twitter App installed ?

Comment: no i haven't installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Twitter app installed in order to use Twitter Sign in.